# winforms - How to make dynamically update stripstatus label when button save clicked in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I just learned C# and just recently I tried to create a simple word process. I'm confuse how to make dynamically update my stripstatus label when i try to save the document.

Here is my code so far:

```
using System.IO.Enumeration;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Pert3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Font_Style.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        
        private void btBold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(rtbDocument.SelectionFont.Style == FontStyle.Bold)
            {
                rtbDocument.SelectionFont = new Font(
                    rtbDocument.SelectionFont.FontFamily,
                    rtbDocument.SelectionFont.Size,
                    FontStyle.Regular);
            }
            
            else
            {
                rtbDocument.SelectionFont = new Font(
                    rtbDocument.SelectionFont.FontFamily,
                    rtbDocument.SelectionFont.Size,
                    FontStyle.Bold);
            }
        }

        private void btItalic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rtbDocument.SelectionFont.Style == FontStyle.Italic)
            {
                rtbDocument.SelectionFont = new Font(
                    rtbDocument.SelectionFont.FontFamily,
                    rtbDocument.SelectionFont.Size,
                    FontStyle.Regular);
            }

            else
            {
                rtbDocument.SelectionFont = new Font(
                    rtbDocument.SelectionFont.FontFamily,
                    rtbDocument.SelectionFont.Size,
                    FontStyle.Italic);
            }
        }

        private void btUnderline_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rtbDocument.SelectionFont.Style == FontStyle.Underline)
            {
                rtbDocument.SelectionFont = new Font(
                    rtbDocument.SelectionFont.FontFamily,
                    rtbDocument.SelectionFont.Size,
                    FontStyle.Regular);
            }

            else
            {
                rtbDocument.SelectionFont = new Font(
                    rtbDocument.SelectionFont.FontFamily,
                    rtbDocument.SelectionFont.Size,
                    FontStyle.Underline);
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rtbDocument.SelectionFont = new Font(
                Font_Style.Text,
                rtbDocument.SelectionFont.Size,
                rtbDocument.SelectionFont.Style);
        }

        private void FontSize_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rtbDocument.SelectionFont = new Font(
                rtbDocument.SelectionFont.FontFamily,
                (float)FontSize.Value,
                rtbDocument.SelectionFont.Style);
        }

        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Rich Text Format (*.rtf)|*.rtf";
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                rtbDocument.LoadFile(openFileDialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);

                saveFileDialog.FileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (saveFileDialog.FileName == "")
            {
                saveFileDialog.FileName = "";
                saveFileDialog.Filter = "Rich Text Format (*.rtf)|*.rtf";
                if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    rtbDocument.SaveFile(saveFileDialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                rtbDocument.SaveFile(saveFileDialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
            }
        }

        private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveDlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            string filename = "";

            // To filter files from SaveFileDialog
            saveDlg.Filter = "Rich Text File (*.rtf)|*.rtf";
            saveDlg.Title = "Save the contents";

            DialogResult retval = saveDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (retval == DialogResult.OK)
                filename = saveDlg.FileName;
            else
                return;

            rtbDocument.SaveFile(filename);
            MessageBox.Show("File Saved");
        }

        private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rtbDocument.Text = "";
            saveFileDialog.FileName = "";
        }
    }
}
```

when the save button clicked i want my stripstatus label update dynamically like this image:

[Before saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duZ86.png) 

[After Saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9lAq.png)

Comment: This is too much code. Create a copy of your project and remove everything that is not needed, e.g. no italics button, no bold button, nothing except what is really needed. We call this a [mre] and it helps focusing on the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see what you haven't done. There is no sign of updating you `StatusStripLabel`'s value.

In `saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click` after successful saving you should change the value of that label.